# how can i get email notification on salesforce from my customers?

Tags: email, notifications, salesforce, alert

ןs it possible to synchronize between my email and salesforce  so that I can send emails to my customers and receive an alert when they reply to the email?
If so I would love to know how to do it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick&dirty way - configure [Email-to-Case](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.customizesupport_email.htm&type=5) and you could be forwarding certain emails (manually? with some automated rule?)

Read up about [`InboundEmailHandler`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_inbound_using.htm) and you could have it bit smarter, piece of code that could find previous messages, reopen cases, link them to right contact...

Bit more involved would be proper Gmail / Office 365 /... mail sync. It used to be called "Lightning Sync" but looks like they're phasing it out. Try https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.einstein_sales_aac.htm&type=5